# android: Sharing layouts between activites

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, android-activity

Suppose i wanted to create a new activity named myActivity.java. How would i let that activity handle any View programatically created in MainActivity.java. For example, if this is a part of the MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
    image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this); 
    image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    getImages();
    i = rnd.nextInt(muchImages);
    setImage();

}
```

and i wanted to create a new activity that would handle my image sliding

I am asking this question because i had a problem where both activities shared the same main_activity.xml, so basically when i called for *myActivity* the part that was programatically created in main activity was not there, because *myActivity* could not see it. How do I achieve that both Views created in *MainActivity* **and** in *myActivity* are shown in the main.xml at the same time? Should *myActivity* create its own layout and than somehow add it to main.xml?

Forgive me i'm an android newbie. Ty for your time

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to do that as making it work will rapidly get very ugly - you'll have to insure that all the manipulation is done relative to the owning Activity, rather than the Activity holding the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create views in `onCreate()` dynamically as you did for `ImageView`.  Add view(s) to `Layout`.

```
LinearLayout2.addView(image);
```

You can also use `removeView()` when you no longer need it.

```
LinearLayout2.removeView(image);
```